# Is it possible to solve those differential equations (with complex numbers)?

Tags: differential-equations, non-linear-optics, photonics

[image]I'm trying to solve this equation, I don't know where to begin with. Is it feasible ? If so how should I solve it ?

[https://www.osapublishing.org/oe/fulltext.cfm?uri=oe-20-7-7454&id=230426
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8879624[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU3T3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU3T3.png)

Comment: Analytical? I would not even try. But you can obtain a lot of properties without solving it. If you have anything specific in mind with this equation, you should comment it.

Comment: Yes, I would be surprised if there was an analytical solution especially with $P_{in}(t)$ being free (might make a stab at a Laplace transform just in case), but it looks pretty well behaved from a numerical solution standpoint.

Comment: Two complex ODEs is just four real ODEs (if $n$ is real, then 3 ODEs). Four ODEs can easily be solved numerically, using Matlab or similar software.

Comment: @Grego_gc Actually my goal is, knowing that b(output) = sqrt(P(in)) - constant*a (the "a" of the differential equation), to be able to express b(output) as a function of P(in) : b(output) = f(P(in)). I need to be able to quickly find b(output) for any P(in).